# Azure Synapse refuses to use default headers

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake

still a bit new to this and would appreciate some help.

I have a pipeline in Azure Synapse Analytics where it receives a file from an API. The file has the default headers of "Prop_0", "Prop_1" etc... instead of its first row as header.

Went to the settings for that integration dataset and the first row as header option has been selected but it keeps using the default columns.

[image: Integration Dataset settings]

How can I fix this?

Is there any way I can manually map the columns?

Comment: What is the source of the file? Is it Blob or Is it from API? and what is your linked service for the above dataset? Is it HTTP or Azure Storage type? Can you provide your sample schema of the file?

Comment: The file comes from an API. If you can show me how to provide a sample schema, I can provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question, your source of the file is from an API and the above dataset is your target dataset.

First check the header and schema of your source file whether it contains the correct headers or the `Prop_1`, `Prop_2`,.. like headers from the source itself.

To check the schema of the source file, go to your source dataset and click on schema.

[image]

If here your headers are like Prop_1, Prop_2,.. then it means these are headers are from your source itself. So, you can change the headers from your API if you want.

> Is there any way I can manually map the columns?

If you want to change the headers during the pipeline run, use the mapping in the copy activity.

**NOTE**: This method will only work correct only if your source is static(without any dymamic parameters in its URI). It won't give any problem with sink dynamic parameters.

Go to copy activity **mapping** -> click on **import schemas**. Now, in the destination, you can change the header names as per your requirement.

[image]

Now, debug the pipeline and file will be generated with new headers.

[image]

If you are **dealing with multiple source pages data** and **your source schema is same for every page**,

- first give any URI of yours in the dataset. Set the mapping in the copy activity like above from the URI's schema.
- Now, go to the Pipeline JSON and copy the object of the `translator` key in this.

  [image]
- Again, go the copy activity mapping and here click on dynamic content and give the above JSON in `@json('above copied JSON')`.

  **My sample:**

  ```
  @json('{
                      "type": "TabularTranslator",
                      "mappings": [
                          {
                              "source": {
                                  "name": "Prop_0",
                                  "type": "String",
                                  "physicalType": "String"
                              },
                              "sink": {
                                  "name": "Id",
                                  "physicalType": "String"
                              }
                          },
                          {
                              "source": {
                                  "name": "Prop_1",
                                  "type": "String",
                                  "physicalType": "String"
                              },
                              "sink": {
                                  "name": "Name",
                                  "physicalType": "String"
                              }
                          },
                          {
                              "source": {
                                  "name": "Prop_2",
                                  "type": "String",
                                  "physicalType": "String"
                              },
                              "sink": {
                                  "name": "Age",
                                  "physicalType": "String"
                              }
                          },
                          {
                              "source": {
                                  "name": "Prop_3",
                                  "type": "String",
                                  "physicalType": "String"
                              },
                              "sink": {
                                  "name": "DOB",
                                  "physicalType": "String"
                              }
                          }
                      ],
                      "typeConversion": true,
                      "typeConversionSettings": {
                          "allowDataTruncation": true,
                          "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                      }
                  }
              }')
  ```

  [image]

  This ensures that for every page even though the URI is dynamic, the same schema for target will be applied.

Comment: With clicking on import schema on the mapping tab, I have this error where I have to give parameters "Please provide actual value of the parameters to get schema" and the parameter is `@item()`  which I don't know what put in as it is used to get individual values from a list of values.

Comment: Observe the list which you are passing to the foreach activity and pass a sample value from it as @item() value for the first time.

Comment: --That worked thank you. Just a final question, any way I can copy this schema and apply it to other pipelines of the same nature? I have quite a few pipelines and find doing this 30+ times a bit too long.-- Oh you answered this, my bad. I apologise!

Comment: Yes only if same nature, but you need to make sure that you provide correct values in those particular pipelines.